# How to get data from Controller to view in codeigniter and print on view

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to get data from controller to view in codeigniter and print on
view, I am sending my data to view but on the view if I'm doing `print_r($data);`, then nothing is showing

How can I get data onto the view?

How can I display there on view where we break array, on view, or controller, or model

Controller Code:

```
public function hopital_list($page = NULL)  {
    // getting hospital details
    $data = $this->hospitals_model->hospital_list();
    $this->load->view('catalog/view_hospitals_list', $data);           
}
```

Model Code:

```
public function hospital_list() {
    // getting hospital details
    $query = $this->db->get('wl_hospitals');

    return  $result = $query->result();    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We are not passing `$data` as a variable in CodeIgniter.

We are actually, passing keys of `$data` to be accessed as arrays/variables in view.

So, the corrected code should be:

```
$data['hospitals'] = $this->hospitals_model->hospital_list();
```

To print:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($hospitals);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 $data['hospitals_list'] = $this->hospitals_model->hospital_list();



   $this->load->view('catalog/view_hospitals_list', $data);


}
```

Access $hospitals_list in your view.

View :

```
foreach($hospitals_list as $row){
  //your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function hospital_list() {
    $data = $query->result();

    if ($data) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($data as $dataP) {
            $menuName['view1'] = $dataP->view1;
            $menuName[$i]['view2'] = $dataP->view2;
            $menuName[$i]['view3'] = $dataP->view3;
            $menuName[$i]['view4'] = $dataP->view4;
            $i++;
        }
    }
    return $menuName;
}
```